# dev deploy complaining about closures

Tags: php, laravel, routes, closures

I ran `deb deploy` and it got down to this point.

```
  The command "/usr/bin/php ~/NetTube/releases/1/artisan optimize" failed.

  Exit Code: 1 (General error)

  Host Name: 68.183.20.108

  ================
  Configuration cache cleared!
  Configuration cached successfully!
  Route cache cleared!

  In Route.php line 917:

    Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.
```

I've looked into this and it seems that I can't use closures with routes, which is fine. I'm just not sure how to prevent closures.

This is  my web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('welcome');
// });

Route::get('/','HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

// Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
    Route::get('/upload','VideoUploadController@index');

    Route::get('/channel/{channel}/edit','ChannelSettingsController@edit');
    Route::put('/channel/{channel}/edit','ChannelSettingsController@update');
});


Route::get('/channel/{channel}','ChannelController@index');
Route::get('/{channel}','ChannelController@index');
```

I have tried putting the routes not in a group with

```
Route::get('/upload', [
    'uses' => 'VideoUploadController@index',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

Route::get('/channel/{channel}/edit', [
    'uses' => 'ChannelSettingsController@edit',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

Route::put('/channel/{channel}/edit', [
    'uses' => 'ChannelSettingsController@update',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

I am running laravel 6.17.1. I hope I gave enough information to anybody that can help.

Comment: I know from trying to search myself that I need to put my routes in controllers but I thought that's what I was doing with `ChannelSettingsController@edit` for example

Comment: Look into api.php a route with 'user' uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem resides on the `routes\api.php`.

Do something like `Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 'MyProfileController@index');`. This route needs to be binded to a controller. If you don't need the route, comment or delete it.